# How many ways are there to split $12$ people into $4$ groups with $3$ people in each group?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to split $12$ people into $4$ groups with $3$ people in each group?

I have tried to write all the possible ways to do it, and came up with $\frac{12!}{(3!)^3}\cdot4!$, however I am still wrong.

Comment: Quick hint: You can use MathJax to write equations out like this: $\frac{12!}{(3!)^3}\times4!$ This comes from this: `$\frac{12!}{(3!)^3}\times4!$`

Comment: @gadzooks02, unless, of course, the original poster mean `\frac{12!}{(3!)^3\times 4!}` which is *closer* to the correct answer.

Comment: @GrahamKemp True. We have no way to know, though unless the OP comments.

Answer (score 2):

> I have tried to write all the possible ways to do it, and came up with $\frac{12!}{(3!)^3}\cdot4!$, however I am still wrong.

The answer you seek is $$\dfrac{12!}{(3!)^\mathbf 4\cdot 4!}$$

There are $12!$ ways to arrange 12 people in a line, and when split into 4 groups, there are $3!$ ways to arrange people in each group, and $4!$ ways to arrange the groups themselves. (Note: since the groups are all of the same size their place-holders are indistinguishable.)

---

For an easier example, there are $4!$ ways to arrange $\{a,b,c,d\}$ in a line, and when split into 2 groups, there are $2!$ ways to arrange letters in each group, and $2!$ ways to arrange the groups themselves.

Since, for example, $\{\{a,b\},\{c,d\}\}$ is considered indistinguishable from $\{\{d,c\},\{b,a\}\}$, and other permutations *within* the groups and *of* the groups, we must count fewer (and therefore divide).

$$\dfrac{4!}{(2!)^2\cdot 2!}=3\\~\\ \{\{a,b\},\{c,d\}\}\\\{\{a,c\},\{b,d\}\}\\\{\{a,d\},\{b,c\}\}$$

Answer (score 0):

One method may be choose 3 people from 12 then 3 from 9.....  $$\binom{12}3.\binom{9}3\binom{6}3.\binom{3}3.{1 \over 4!}$$

I didn't understood logic behind your attempt

Comment: Note that if the groups are ordered, then your approach works, but if the groups are unordered, then you have an extra factor of $4!$.

Comment: however look at the end of the equation, I had added the 4!

Comment: Yeah you are correct . but nothing is described in question . I  assumed all groups are same

Comment: I'm sorry- That was the question that was provided to me...

Comment: $\dfrac{12!}{(3!)^4}=\dbinom{12}3\dbinom93\dbinom 63\dbinom 33$, but you must then divide by $4!$ (*not* multiply) since the arrangements of the groups can be divided into sets of $4!$ indistinguishable arrangement.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is 5775. There are (12! divided by (4!4!4!) ) ways to divide the people into a Team A, a Team B, and a Team C, if we care about which team is which (this is called a multinomial coefficient).

Since here it doesn’t matter which team is which, this overcounts by a factor of 3! , so the number of possibilities is 12! divided by $(4!4!4!3!) = 5775$